# Using std::vector for saving BMP pixel map

Tags: c++, image, bmp

I'm using std::vector for saving pixel map of BMP image:

```cpp
struct BGR {
  BYTE &operator[](const BMPCOLORS &color)
  {
    switch (color) {
      case BLUE: return b;
      case GREEN: return g;
      case RED: return r;
    }
    throw ERROR_OUT_OF_BOUNDS;
  }

  DWORD operator()() //return rgb
  {
    return static_cast <DWORD> ((r << 16) | (g << 8) | b);
  }

  BGR()
  : b(0), g(0), r(0)
  {}

  BGR(const BYTE *BGR) : b(BGR[0]), g(BGR[1]), r(BGR[2]) {}
  BGR(BYTE blue, BYTE green, BYTE red) : b(blue), g(green), r(red) {}
  BYTE b, g, r;
};
```

And function of reading pixel map looks like:

```cpp
int BMPimage::ReadImagePixels(void)
{
  if (!my_image_->working_file.is_open())
    return BMP_ERR_READING_FILE;

  DWORD height = my_image_->height;
  DWORD width = my_image_->width;

  BYTE pad_offset = static_cast <BYTE> (( ((width * 3 + 3) & static_cast <unsigned int> (~3)) - (width * 3) ) * sizeof(BYTE));
  BGR temp;

  my_image_->working_file.seekg(my_image_->file_header->bfOffBits);

  for (unsigned int row = 0; row < width; row++)
  {
    for (unsigned int col = 0; col < height; col++)
    {
        my_image_->working_file.read(reinterpret_cast <char*> (&temp), sizeof(BGR));
        pixels.push_back(temp);
    }
    my_image_->working_file.seekg(pad_offset, std::ios::cur);
  }

  return BMP_OK;
}
```

There `my_image_->height` and `my_image_->width` takes values from BITMAPINFOHEADER, so it should be correct (I've checked functions of reading BMP headers and it's correct).

But in some cases with correct types of images (24 bit format and V3 Microsoft version there isn't any compression) I'm getting errors of **out of range**:

`terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'  what():  vector::_M_range_check: __n (which is 262144) >= this->size() (which is 262144)`

Example of the function there I get it:

```cpp
int ImgEdit::make_black_and_white()
{
    int width = static_cast<int> (bmpImg->get_width());
    int height = static_cast<int> (bmpImg->get_height());
    int avg;

    for (int row = 0; row < width; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < height; col++)
        {
            avg = (bmpImg->pixels.at(static_cast<unsigned long> ( (row * width) + col)).r +
            bmpImg->pixels.at(static_cast<unsigned long> ( (row * width) + col)).g +
            bmpImg->pixels.at(static_cast<unsigned long> ( (row * width) + col)).b) / 3;
            bmpImg->pixels.at(static_cast<unsigned long> ( (row * width) + col)).r = static_cast<unsigned char>(avg);
            bmpImg->pixels.at(static_cast<unsigned long> ( (row * width) + col)).g = static_cast<unsigned char>(avg);
            bmpImg->pixels.at(static_cast<unsigned long> ( (row * width) + col)).b = static_cast<unsigned char>(avg);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If I try to use `try-catch` this exception I get black and white result image with color line on left side. So I don't understand why it happened and how to correct this errors with vector.

P.S. I'm working on Linux system so I've defined:

```
typedef uint8_t BYTE;
typedef uint16_t WORD;
typedef uint32_t DWORD;
```

Comment: instead of `i` and `j` use `row` and `col`, it is much clearer.. `(i * width) + j` should be `(j * width) + i` where `j` means `row` and `i` is `col`.

Comment: @Scheff I've added `__attribute__((packed))` and nothing changed.

Comment: I tried on coliru (with g++) and even that worked (even without `__attribute__((packed))`) (although I wouldn't sell my grandma for this). I came to the conclusion that @rafix07 nailed it. For non-square images, which would be a reasonable explanation for out-of-range accesses. (I looked up and down but couldn't find anything else though this doesn't need to mean anything...) ;-)

Comment: Ehem! `for (int row = 0; row < width; row++)` **!** Should be: `for (int row = 0; row < height; row++)`. The inner loop is wrong as well. ;-)

Comment: @Scheff That’s very kind of you! It's tru

Comment: BTW, doing all those `push_back` one at time is slow for no good reason... Preallocate the whole thing with a `resize` at start, and read whole scanlines. Also, passing BMPCOLORS (it's an `enum`, right?) by const reference makes zero sense. Passing integer-sized arguments by const reference is a pessimization, both from a conceptual and a performance standpoint.

Comment: Also: `.at` in a pixel loop makes me weep, you are going probably an order of magnitude slower than is possible. Just fetch a reference/pointer to the required pixel once in the inner loop; you can check for out of boundary access using debug STL in test builds, without paying for `.at` overhead in "regular" ones. Even better: as you don't care of actual x/y values, just use a range-based `for` over `pixels` with a `BGR &` - that isn't going to be out of boundaries by definition.

Comment: `std::getline` has no place here - you are reading binary data! That would be more like `pixels.resize(width*height);
for(unsigned row = 0; row < height; ++row) {
    my_image_->working_file.read((char *)&pixels[row*width], width*sizeof(BGR));
    my_image_->working_file.seekg(pad_offset, std::ios::cur);
}
`

Answer (score 0):

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'  what():  
vector::_M_range_check: __n (which is 262144) >= this->size() (which is 262144)
```

This happends because the `std::vector` checks if you indices are in a valid range.

Your particular issue seems to stem from that you have switched up `width` and `height` in the loop code.

Comment: _in debug builds_ no, `.at` checks the index always.

Comment: @MatteoItalia true, and fixed that